# Issues with LWP logging into website

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp

I am new to LWP and thanks for all the help. I am writing a small perl script to log into a website and download a file. The process works perfectly fine with a browser but not through LWP. With a browser the process is

1. Log into website via authentication (username, password)
2. Upon successful login, the wesbite loads another page
3. One can then access the Downloads page and download the file
4. In case one is not logged in and tries to access the download page, the website
   loads the Registration page to create a login.

This process works perfectly fine with a browser. The URL and user/pass are real so you can try this on the website with the details in the code

With a script however, I get a success code but the website does not allow access to steps 2 or 3. Instead of downloading the file, the Registration page gets downloaded. I suspect that this means that login is not working with the script.

All help in making this work will be greatly appreciated

Code below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Request;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $base_url = "http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx";
my $username = 'xcytt';
my $password = '321pass';

# create a cookie jar on disk
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new(
    file     => 'cookies1.txt',
    autosave => 1,
);

my $http = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$http->cookie_jar($cookies);

my $login = $http->post(
    'http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx',
    Content => [
        username => $username,
        password => $password,
    ]
);

# check if log in succeeded

if ( $login->is_success ) {
    print "The response from server is " . $login->status_line . "\n\n";
    print "The headers in the response are \n" . $login->headers()->as_string() . "\n\n";
    print "Logged in Successfully\n\n";
    print "Printing cookies after successful login\n\n";
    print $http->cookie_jar->as_string() . "\n";
    my $url = "http://www.eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE";
    print "Now trying to download " . $url . "\n\n";

    # make request to download the file
    my $file_req = HTTP::Request->new( 'GET', $url );
    print "Printing cookies before file download request\n\n";
    print $http->cookie_jar->as_string() . "\n";
    my $get_file = $http->request($file_req);

    # check request status
    if ( $get_file->is_success ) {
        print "The response from server is " . $get_file->status_line . "\n\n";
        print "The headers in the response are " . $get_file->headers()->as_string() . "\n\n";
        print "Downloaded $url, saving it to file ...\n\n";
        open my $fh, '>', 'tmp_NYSE.txt' or die "ERROR: $!n";
        print $fh $get_file->decoded_content;
        close $fh;
    } else {
        print "File Download failure\n";
    }
} else {
    print "Login Error\n";
}
```

Output from the script:

```
The response from server is 200 OK

The headers in the response are 
Cache-Control: private
Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:43:47 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Length: 39356
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:43:48 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.182.238.14:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Link: <styles/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/main.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/button.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/nav.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: </styles/colorbox.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: </styles/slides.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=cjgm4oscl1xmlzwnzql4gcns; path=/; HttpOnly
Title: End of Day Stock Quote Data and Historical Stock Prices
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Meta-Description: Free end of day stock market data and historical quotes for many of the world's top exchanges including NASDAQ, NYSE, AMEX, TSX, OTCBB, FTSE, SGX, HKEX, and FOREX.
X-Meta-Keywords: metastock eod,free eod,free eod data,eod download,stock,exchange,data,historical stock quotes,free,historical share prices,download,day,end,prices,market,chart,NYSE,NASDAQ,AMEX,FTSE,FOREX,ASX,SGX,NZSE,tsx stock,stock share prices,stock ticker symbol,daily prices,daily stock,historic stock price,stock futures
X-Meta-Verify-V1: cT9ZK5uSlR3GrcasqgUh7Yh3fnuRGsRY1IRvE85ffa0=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


Logged in Successfully

Printing cookies after successful login

Set-Cookie3: ASP.NET_SessionId=cjgm4oscl1xmlzwnzql4gcns; path="/"; domain=www.eoddata.com; path_spec; discard; HttpOnly; version=0

Now trying to download http://www.eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE

Printing cookies before file download request

Set-Cookie3: ASP.NET_SessionId=cjgm4oscl1xmlzwnzql4gcns; path="/"; domain=www.eoddata.com; path_spec; discard; HttpOnly; version=0

The response from server is 200 OK

The headers in the response are Cache-Control: private
Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:43:48 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Length: 49880
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:43:49 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.182.238.14:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Link: <styles/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/main.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/button.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Link: <styles/nav.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Title: Member Registration
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Meta-Description: Register now for Free end of day stock market data and historical quotes for many of the world's top exchanges including NASDAQ, NYSE, AMEX, TSX, OTCBB, FTSE, ASX, SGX, HKEX, and FOREX.
X-Meta-Keywords: metastock eod,free eod,free eod data,eod download,stock,exchange,data,historical stock quotes,free,download,day,end,prices,market,chart,NYSE,NASDAQ,AMEX,FTSE,FOREX,ASX,SGX,NZSE,tsx stock,stock share prices,stock ticker symbol,daily prices,daily stock,historic stock price
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


Downloaded http://www.eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE, saving it to file ...
```

The header from the browser is:

```
http://www.eoddata.com/myaccount/default.aspx

GET /Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE HTTP/1.1
Host: www.eoddata.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=uvnqhzpzco1wpe300egm4hqj; __utma=264658075.1162754774.1412987203.1413069850.1413137050.4; __utmc=264658075; __utmz=264658075.1412987203.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _cb_ls=1; _chartbeat2=DMtSRyBOnGNFDptR86.1412466246942.1413137060190.10011111; _chartbeat_uuniq=3; EODDataAdmin=D838F9AA985E247A47493320CC8DC14950FA6CE49C6E1079DCFA95F632CEA7A2A6A691B352C544D41D0C208077D0C23897C9EA6EF0FE9221833A7131C334A657A48F5001BF2EBDE073D98BE4FD5719943AAC94D7C3DAA5A422FD575C663C337C93D5046AF3F7987998EDD60347531460FC54DEC81394352D9EDA00B7C954CC3304BC7D4C30D1F3A82C0EE58B890E0765; __utmb=264658075.2.10.1413137050; __utmt=1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=NYSE.txt
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 18:05:24 GMT
```

The downloaded file snippet which is NOT the output I want is below. Note that the title is "Member Registration" instead of the data file I am expecting

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/button.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nav.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     var _sf_startpt = (new Date()).getTime()</script>
<meta name="keywords" content="metastock eod,free eod,free eod data,eod download,stock,exchange,data,historical stock quotes,free,download,day,end,prices,market,chart,NYSE,NASDAQ,AMEX,FTSE,FOREX,ASX,SGX,NZSE,tsx stock,stock share prices,stock ticker symbol,daily prices,daily stock,historic stock price" />
<meta name="description" content="Register now for Free end of day stock market data and historical quotes for many of the world's top exchanges including NASDAQ, NYSE, AMEX, TSX, OTCBB, FTSE, ASX, SGX, HKEX, and FOREX." />
<title>
Member Registration
</title></head>
```

Comment: Your initial login code isn't working, which is part of the issue--if you perform the login in a browser and examine the data transmitted (e.g. using Chrome's inspector panel), you'll see that the data sent when the form is submitted has numerous inputs not present in your login request, and that the cookie set in the browser after a successful login is very different from that in LWP::UA's cookie jar.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those `use` statements are unnecessary, as LWP will generally pull in any modules that it needs.

If you are using `LWP::UserAgent` then you *certainly* don't need `LWP::Simple` or`WWW::Mechanize`, and by default LWP will create an in-memory `HTTP::Cookies` object.

The problem is most likely that the HTML that you are fetching from the web site contains JavaScript code that modifies it *after* it is retrieved. LWP won't emulate that for you, so the page remains just as it was sent from the web site.

There is no good solution to this, but [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) allows you to drive an installed Firefox browser from Perl code, and will do what you need.

Comment: This isn't a Javascript issue as it is possible to log into the site with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your login code isn't logging you in--the data you are posting doesn't resemble the input that the login form takes.

Using `WWW::Mechanize`'s `mech-dump` to examine the contents of the form at `http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx` shows the following:

```
POST http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx [aspnetForm]
  ctl00_tsm_HiddenField=         (hidden readonly)
  __VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUJNTgzMTIzMjMyD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgcPZBYCAh0PZBYEAgMPZBYCAgcPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkAgcPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBRpjdGwwMCRjcGgxJGxnMSRjaGtSZW1lbWJlcuq72b0jSSSEoSOAcZlLZzWMmsYqjOMTbPl/Op1ToVKf (hidden readonly)
  __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334  (hidden readonly)
  __PREVIOUSPAGE=72Ep8BrmYqNbOSb65afxljULshovHpRLBJcMC0funBrM2g0qkkpORQb_wqNsu_2SbA5JbxbwNkpXlR_SZWwgPwwbGdBP4YGDoNJCDtPRQS81 (hidden readonly)
  __EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAvsaJw1zF2h8PWbp8tJHjaFx+CzKn9gssNaJswg1PWksJd223BvmKj73tdq9M98Zo0JWPh42opnSCw9zAHys7YwDyn98qMl4Da8RNKOYtjmMtj1Nek/A8Dky1WNDflwB7GO1vgbcIR7aON1c4Cm5wJw0r2yvex8d7TohORX6QMo1j8IRvmRE3IYRPV0S4fj4csX1838LMsOJxqMoksh8zNIRuOmXf1pY8AyXSwvWgp1mYRx4mHFI6oep3qpPKhhA22Mc6tB5KOFIqkGgyvucIby (hidden readonly)
  ctl00$Menu1$s1$txtSearch=      (text)
  ctl00$Menu1$s1$btnSearch=Search (submit)
  ctl00$cph1$btns1=CLICK HERE    (submit)
  ctl00$cph1$btns2=CLICK HERE    (submit)
  ctl00$cph1$btns3=CLICK HERE    (submit)
  ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtEmail=       (text)
  ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtPassword=    (password)
  ctl00$cph1$lg1$chkRemember=<UNDEF> (checkbox) [*<UNDEF>/off|on]
  ctl00$cph1$lg1$btnLogin=Login  (submit)
```

Your POST request needs to set the appropriate fields from the form above to successfully log in to the server, unless there is documentation somewhere that specifically says that the method you are using to login is valid (I did not do a search of the website to check this).

I cheated somewhat and created a valid login request using data from Chrome's inspector panel (rather than using WWW::Mechanize to populate the form or creating the request myself). With this, I was able to login and download the file:

```
my $resp = $http->post(
    'http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx',
    Content => 'ctl00_tsm_HiddenField=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJNTgzMTIzMjMyD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgcPZBYCAh0PZBYEAgMPZBYCAgcPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkAgcPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBRpjdGwwMCRjcGgxJGxnMSRjaGtSZW1lbWJlcuq72b0jSSSEoSOAcZlLZzWMmsYqjOMTbPl%2FOp1ToVKf&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334&__PREVIOUSPAGE=72Ep8BrmYqNbOSb65afxljULshovHpRLBJcMC0funBrM2g0qkkpORQb_wqNsu_2SbA5JbxbwNkpXlR_SZWwgPwwbGdBP4YGDoNJCDtPRQS81&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAvsaJw1zF2h8PWbp8tJHjaFx%2BCzKn9gssNaJswg1PWksJd223BvmKj73tdq9M98Zo0JWPh42opnSCw9zAHys7YwDyn98qMl4Da8RNKOYtjmMtj1Nek%2FA8Dky1WNDflwB7GO1vgbcIR7aON1c4Cm5wJw0r2yvex8d7TohORX6QMo1j8IRvmRE3IYRPV0S4fj4csX1838LMsOJxqMoksh8zNIRuOmXf1pY8AyXSwvWgp1mYRx4mHFI6oep3qpPKhhA22Mc6tB5KOFIqkGgyvucIby&ctl00%24Menu1%24s1%24txtSearch=&ctl00%24cph1%24lg1%24txtEmail=xcytt&ctl00%24cph1%24lg1%24txtPassword=321pass&ctl00%24cph1%24lg1%24btnLogin=Login' );

if ($resp->is_success) {    
    my $get_file = $http->get("http://www.eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE");
}
```

Dumping the contents of `$get_file` gave me the list of symbols and company names as expected.

You can use WWW::Mechanize to fill in the form fields, or you can scrape the form input values from `http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx` (particularly the hidden fields, which change on every page load) and then create a POST request using those values and your login credentials.

Also note that it is perfectly possible to get a successful response from the server without performing the action (e.g. login) that you were intending. Redirects and pages with "Login failed" will both be counted as success by LWP::UA.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is stil interested in this problem, I have taken another look at it and found that it is quite workable using just `LWP`. However, the facilities of [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) make it much more simple to work with HTML forms

Here's a program that logs in to the page using the credentials provided. Being an ASP page it has dreadful input names. For instance the names if the username and password fields and the login button are `ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtEmail`, `ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtPassword`, and `ctl00$cph1$lg1$btnLogin` respectively. I have used the [`HTML::Form`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Form) methods directly to locate these input fields using regular expressions, which I think makes the code much clearer

I have displayed the title of the HTML page that is reached after logging in to demonstrate that it is working

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $base_url = 'http://www.eoddata.com/default.aspx';
my $username = 'xcytt';
my $password = '321pass';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get($base_url);

my $form = $mech->form_id('aspnetForm');

my @inputs  = $form->inputs;
my ($email) = grep $_->name =~ /Email/,    @inputs;
my ($pass)  = grep $_->name =~ /Password/, @inputs;
my ($login) = grep $_->name =~ /Login/,    @inputs;

$email->value($username);
$pass->value($password);
$mech->click_button(value => 'Login');

print $mech->title, "\n";
```

#### output

```
EODData - My Download
```